# Why this command does not giving alphabetical order?

Tags: php, html, sql, wordpress

I am making a query in wordpress website using mysql and listing the speakers in the following way.

```
<div class="invited_speakers_list">
<ul>
    <?php
        global $wpdb;
        $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM  `Invited_Speakers_auto` ORDER BY 'Last_Name' ASC;");
        foreach($result as $print){ 
    ?>
<li> 
<?php echo $print->First_Name;?> <?php echo $print->Last_Name;?>, <?php echo $print->Institute_Address;?>
</li>
    <?php } ?>    
</ul>
</div>
```

According to the command this should give me alphetical order by last name in the output.

But it doesnot. [click here](http://iclaa2017.com/testpage/) to see the list of invited speakers where the error persists.

Why?

Where I have made mistake?

Kindly help me out in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `'Last_Name'` is a string literal, not a column name. I.e. all rows will have the same sort value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your Query Should Be

```
"SELECT * FROM  `Invited_Speakers_auto` ORDER BY `Last_Name` ASC"
```

Answer (score 1):

you should change (') to (`) for lastname

(') it changing to string and not a column name